# How to find the highest attribute in a dataset, then display the "name" associated with that

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm still relatively new to programming and I have a project I am working on. I am making a staff efficiency dashboard for a fictional pizza company. I want to find the quickest pizza making time and display the time and the staff members name to the user.

With the data charts it has been easy. Create a function, then use dc, e.g dc.barChart("#idOfDivInHtmlPage")

I suspect I might be trying to be too complicated, and that I've completely forgotten how to display any outputs of a js function to a html page.

I've been using d3.js, dc.js and crossfilter to represent most of the data visually in an interactive way.

Snippet of the .csv

```
Name,Rank,YearsService,Course,PizzaTime
Scott,Instore,3,BMC,96
Mark,Instore,4,Intro,94
Wendy,Instore,3,Intro,76
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    var timeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return [d.PizzaTime, d.Name]
    });

    var minStaffPizzaTimeName = timeDim.bottom(1)[0].PizzaTime;
    var maxStaffPizzaTimeName = timeDim.top(1)[0].PizzaTime;

}
```

then in the html

```
<p id="minStaffPizzaTimeName"></p>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/graph.js">
                document.write("minStaffPizzaTimeName");
            </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use the [dc.js] tag for questions regarding the charting library. [dc] is a classic unix calculator utility. Also, vague tags like [javascript] tend to attract people who don't know what they are looking at, who often react negatively - best to use the most specific tags. I've fixed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boom, finally figured it out.

```
function show_fastest_and_slowest_pizza_maker(ndx) {

    var timeDim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("PizzaTime"));

    var minPizzaTimeName = timeDim.bottom(1)[0].Name;
    var maxPizzaTimeName = timeDim.top(1)[0].Name;

    d3.select('#minPizzaTimeName')
        .text(minPizzaTimeName);
    d3.select('#maxPizzaTimeName')
        .text(maxPizzaTimeName);

}
```

Thanks very much Gordon, you sent me down the right path!

Answer (score 0):

You are surely on the right track, but in javascript you often have to consider the timing of when things will happen.

`document.write()` (or rather, anything at the top level of a script) will get executed *while the page is getting loaded*.

But I bet your data is loaded *asynchronously* (probably with `d3.csv`), so you won't have a crossfilter object until a bit later. You haven't shown these parts but that's the usual way to use crossfilter and dc.js.

So you will need to modify the page after it's loaded. D3 is great for this! (The straight javascript way to do this particular thing isn't much harder.)

You should be able to leave the `<p>` tag where it is, remove the extra `<script>` tag, and then, in the function which creates `timeDim`:

```
d3.select('#minStaffPizzaTimeName').text(minStaffPizzaTimeName);
```

This looks for the element with that ID and replaces its content with the value you have computed.

#### General problem solving tools

You can use the dev tools dom inspector to make sure that the `p` tag exists with id `minStaffPizzaTimeName`.

You can also use

```
console.log(minStaffPizzaTimeName)
```

to see if you are fetching the data correctly.

It's hard to tell without a running example but I think you will want to define your dimension using the PizzaTime only, and convert it from a string to a number:

```
var timeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return +d.PizzaTime;
});
```

Then `timeDim.bottom(1)[0]` should give you the row of your original data with the lowest value of `PizzaTime`. Adding `.Name` to that expression should retrieve the name field from the row object.

But you might have to poke around using `console.log` or the interactive debugger to find the exact expression that works. It's pretty much impossible to use dc.js or D3 without these tools, so a little investment in learning them will pay off big time.

Comment: Hi, thanks, for helping out!
Data loaded with d3.csv. 
I've made your suggested changes (I think), I still have no errors, just no output.

Comment: Okay, I think I found one problem, but more importantly, I've added some tips for how to troubleshoot these problems in general. Hope it helps!